# CRM 2013 Plugin Registration Connection Error: Unable to connect to the CRM Organization

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am using Plugin Registration Tool in CRM SDK 2013. When creating new connection to CRM 2013 Online, I get the error: "Unable to connect to the CRM Organization". The details is as below:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl.CrmServerLoginControl.StartConnectCheck()
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.PluginRegistration.MainViewModel.CreateConnections()
```

The error shows even when I click Login without username and password.

I tried deleting LiveDevice.xml and LiveDeviceID.xml in C:\Users\\LiveDeviceID folder, but it's no use.

Any idea or workaround is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I tried registration tool in SDK 2011, somehow it can connect successfully. However, I can't debug my plugins because of datacontract parsing, I can only register/unregister plugins.

Answer (score 4):

Ok i got this working by deleting the following AppData folder as I getting an access denied error in the pluginregistration tool log file. C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\PluginRegistration.

Comment: Thanks. This may solve the issue. Now I am moving on with CRM 2015 and the new registration tool works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is specific to the failure to find the organization that you are connecting to. Please double check with the discovery URL for your CRM online instance under **Settings > Customizations > Developer Resources**

For CRM Online 2013, it would be 'https://disco.crm.dynamics.com' and not 'https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com'

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with my plugin registration tool... Upgrading to the newest version worked for me.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded a new SDK like you said, but the same error still appears :-(